# Double Iteration loop for NDWi Calculation in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to create a double iteration loop to calculate max NDWI for multiple features (in the code, I have given two adjacent shapefiles). In first iteration, I want to iterate years and in inner iteration, I want to iterate multiple features which will be used as NDWI calculation boundary. Hence inner loop will return the sum of all features for a year and outer loop will sum up all the years output into one. But I am receiving error "Image.select: Pattern 'ndwi_max' did not match any bands." Can someone help in resolving this? (Note: Is it possible to get the individual year images also from the inner loop along with the whole merged composite?)

the code is : 
https://code.earthengine.google.com/d5b2b9c7bfdf36327f601eb3cef51391

``````````````````````````````````````
Map.centerObject(basin,8);
Map.addLayer(basin);

var startDay = '-01-01';
var endDay = '-12-31';
// var yearNow = ee.Number(2019);
var yearList = ee.List.sequence(1982,2019);

function maskClouds (image) {
  var scored = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image);
  return image.updateMask(scored.select(['cloud']).lt(20));}

function addNDWILandsat(image) {
    var ndwiL8754 = image.normalizedDifference(['B2', 'B4']).rename('ndwi');
    return image.addBands(ndwiL8754);}

function Sentinelcloud(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);}

function addNDWISentinel(image) {
    var ndwiS21C = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('ndwi');
    return image.addBands(ndwiS21C);}

var featList = ee.FeatureCollection(basin);

var accumulate_year = function(year,imageCollection2){
var yearNow = ee.Number(year);
var output = ee.String('MaxNDWI_').cat(ee.String(yearNow)); 

var accumulate_feature = function(feature,imageCollection1){
var fet = ee.Geometry(feature.geometry());
var startDate = ee.Date(ee.String(yearNow.toInt()).cat(startDay));
var endDate = ee.Date(ee.String(yearNow.toInt()).cat(endDay));

// Landat 4 surface reflection data
var L4coll = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_TOA')
.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
.map(maskClouds)
.map(addNDWILandsat)
// .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',25))
.filterBounds(fet);
// var countL4 = L4coll.size();
// print('Landsat 4 Image Count: ', countL4);

// Landat 5 surface reflection data
var L5coll = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA')
.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
.map(maskClouds)
.map(addNDWILandsat)
// .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',25))
.filterBounds(fet);
// var countL5 = L5coll.size();
// print('Landsat 5 Image Count: ', countL5);

// Landat 7 surface reflection data, fill in the gaps! See USGS pages for more info
var L7coll = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_TOA')
.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
.map(maskClouds)
.map(addNDWILandsat)
// .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',25))
.filterBounds(fet);
// var countL7 = L7coll.size();
// print('Landsat 7 Image Count: ', countL7);
// .map(function(image){
//   var filled1a = image.focal_mean(2, 'square', 'pixels', 1)
//   return filled1a.blend(image);
// })

// // Landat 8 surface reflection data, rename the band names. See USGS pages for more info
var L8coll = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
// .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',5))
.map(maskClouds)
.map(function(image){
  return image.rename(['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'B11']);
})
.map(addNDWILandsat)
.filterBounds(fet);
// var countL8 = L8coll.size();
// print('Landsat 8 Image Count: ', countL8);

// // Sentinel 2 1-C surface reflection data, rename the band names. See USGS pages for more info
var S2coll = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
.map(Sentinelcloud)
.map(addNDWISentinel)
// .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',25))
.filterBounds(fet);
// // merge L5, L7 & L8
// var collection_merge = ee.ImageCollection(L5coll.merge(L7coll));
var collection_merge = ee.ImageCollection(L4coll.merge(L5coll.merge(L7coll.merge(L8coll.merge(S2coll))))).select('ndwi');
// var count = collection_merge.size();
// print('Total Image Count: ', count);

// var withndwiL875 = collection_merge.map(addNDWILandsat).select('ndwi');
var maxL8754 = collection_merge.reduce(ee.Reducer.max()).clip(basin).select('ndwi_max');
var FINALndwi = ee.ImageCollection(maxL8754.gte(0.1).updateMask(srtm30.lte(4000)));
// var stored = ee.ImageCollection(FINALndwi);
return FINALndwi.sum();
};
// var output = ee.String('MaxNDWI_').cat(ee.String(yearNow)); 
// accumulate_feature = ee.Image(accumulate_feature.rename(output));
var yearIndia = ee.ImageCollection(featList.iterate(accumulate_feature,ee.ImageCollection([])));
return yearIndia;
// var a = ee.Image(yearIndia.sum());
// print (a);
// var output = ee.String('MaxNDWI_').cat(ee.String(yearNow)); 
// yearIndia = yearIndia.rename(output);
// return yearIndia.sum().rename('MaxNDWI');
// return yearIndia;

};
// var a = ee.Image(finalIndia);
var finalIndia = ee.ImageCollection(yearList.iterate(accumulate_year,ee.ImageCollection([])));
var a = finalIndia.sum();
print (a);
// print (yearIndia);
// var totalIndia = finalIndia.select('ndwi_max').sum();
// print(totalIndia);
Map.addLayer(a, {bands: ['ndwi_max'], min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['green','red']}, 'FINALndwi');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: a,
  description: 'MaxNDWI',
  scale: 30,
  region: basin,
  maxPixels: 3784216672400
});
`````````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: You probably don't have a band called 'ndwi_max' which exists.  That definitely isn't in landsat collections until you do the band math and rename.